# Spreadsheet Cell Needs To Remain Blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have created a number of automated calculations for my trading business.  However, I need to be able to reflect blank cells with no value at all.

[image]

You will notice that line 47 is completely filled and properly calculated. However, line 48 has no date or entry price.   I need to have column P, Column Q, and Column S reflect blank.  The calculation for each column is below, and the results can be seen in the picture.

Calc under P48 is:

```
=IF($D48="","",IF(OR(AND($D48="buy",$N48>=$C48),AND($D48="sell",$N48<=$C48)),"Win","Loss"))
```

Calc under Q48 is:

```
=IF(AND($P48="Win",$D48="buy"),ABS($N48-$C48)*10000,IF(AND($P48="Win",$D48="sell"),($C48-$N48)*10000,IF(AND($P48="Loss",$D48="buy"),($N48-$C48)*10000,IF(AND($P48="Loss",$D48="sell"),($C48-$N48)*10000))))
```

Lastly calc for s48 is:

```
=IF($P48="Loss",$Q48*1,"")
```

This is a very complicated and detailed spreadsheet.  Can someone help me process these calculations to make them work properly?

Comment: First of all, lines 47 and 48 are not displayed in your screenshot. Although I guess your explanation still applies to lines 38 and 39 respectively, right?

Comment: What if your make your formula for column P start with `=IF($D48="0",` instead? Can column D be used for this? Otherwise you may use `=IF($B48="",`. Of course, then add the same to the last 4 columns.

Comment: I have checked D48 as well.  It should be blank as well.  That may be triggering the others.  However, I cannot get it to go blank instead of the 0.  Here is what the calc looks like right now...   =IFERROR('4hrdata'!$C43,"")

Comment: I was able to clear D48 through cell formatting and removing the 0.  However, that did not trigger any changes to the right.

Comment: You do not have any condition to put blank in your formulas for Q48, and S48 if conditions are not satisfied. That's why it is not turning blank. Taking a simple example putting a formula in currency formatted cell E3 ~=IF(C3>D3,5,"") , if C3 is less than D3 it well turn E3 cell blank. You can yourself check this.

Comment: The formula under Q48 is:  =IF(AND($P48="Win",$D48="buy"),ABS($N48-$C48)*10000,IF(AND($P48="Win",$D48="sell"),($C48-$N48)*10000,IF(AND($P48="Loss",$D48="buy"),($N48-$C48)*10000,IF(AND($P48="Loss",$D48="sell"),($C48-$N48)*10000)))).... where would I place the piece that you recommend?

Comment: I was able to use O48 as my blank condition.  That has cleared all items except for the q48 and below area.   So... we are getting there.

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  I was able to use your advice above to manipulate the data correctly.

Comment: try using [Excel Table.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). It will save the old practice of putting extruded formula below the current last data row. And the table rows are freely extensible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ISBLANK function. 
Column D is not empty since it contains a zero on rows that do not have a date or entry price (like row 48), so I would use either the date column, the entry price column, or both.
In cell P48:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B48),"",IF(OR(AND($D48="buy",$N48>=$C48),AND($D48="sell",$N48<=$C48)),"Win","Loss"))
```

Or - If either the date or the entry price is not filled in, your formula will return a blank cell with this in cell P48:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B48),ISBLANK(C48)),"",IF(OR(AND($D48="buy",$N48>=$C48),AND($D48="sell",$N48<=$C48)),"Win","Loss"))
```

Add ISBLANK to the beginning of columns Q & S formulas too.
S48:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B48),"",IF($P48="Loss",$Q48*1,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer came through trial/error from the suggestions shown above.  I also used File/Option/Advanced to remove all zero entries on the worksheet.  In addition placed a blank condition in Q48.

Comment: If all your formulas started with `=IF($D48="","",`, (leaving in the *else* part your normal formula) that would have been enough. For example, your last formula: `=IF($D48="","",IF($P48="Loss",$Q48*1,""))`.